# ubuntu wireless broadcom 4352

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I am new to both ubuntu and programming, first time posting. I thought it would be fun to install ubuntu on an older laptop but i got stuck. I have read here and other places and tried everything I can muster. I need help. I have added a link to ubuntu pastebin where I have saved a txt called  wareless-info.txt

If anyone can help me it would make my day... many thanks.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yZcGj7FFkm/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: it is Ubuntu 20.04